# Collecting Data from an e-mail with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, parsing, email

I'm reasonably new to Google App Engine (and python) I'm implementing a system that will basically parse an incoming e-mail and store the details in the Data Store. Now I do have it working but I feel like there should be a better way to do it that I currently am.

Basically, the e-mail that comes in to the system always looks like the following:

```
Order Details: Random Batch Name here

Order Status: 74 of 131 Shipped In Total

Message ID: 123456

Message Date: 21/04/2011 16:13:00

Mobile Number: 01234567890

Message: message would be here
```

The code I am using to parse it looks like this:

```
class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, message):

        # Get the body text from the e-mail
        plaintext_bodies = message.bodies('text/plain')
        for content_type, body in plaintext_bodies:
            body_text = body.decode().split('\n')

            # Loop through each line in the e-mail and discard a line if it is blank
            for line in body_text:
                if line != "":

                    # I'm sure there's a better way of doing this, just don't know how right now!
                    # Split the current line based on the ": " value and only let it be done once
                    splitline = line.split(': ', 1)

                    # Check to see which line we now have the details for and place value into the correct variable
                    if splitline[0] == "Order Details":
                        batch = splitline[1]
                    if splitline[0] == "Message ID":
                        messageID = splitline[1]
                    if splitline[0] == "Message Date":
                        messageDate = splitline[1]
                    if splitline[0] == "Mobile Number":
                        mobileNumber = splitline[1]
                    if splitline[0] == "Message":
                        theMessage = splitline[1]


        newNumber = SMSNumber( status = "Waiting",
                               batch = common.slugify(batch),
                               messageID = messageID,
                               messageDate = messageDate,
                               sentMessage = theMessage )

        newNumber._key_name = mobileNumber
        newNumber.put()
```

Is there a better way to handle this? If anyone has any input it would be gratefully received! :)

Regards

Comment: What does "better" mean?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html  maybe this one?

`import email
>>> msg = email.message_from_string(myString)`

Answer (score 0):

A neater approach would be to iterate through the lines of the file, splitting on the colon, and adding the lines to a `Map`. Then, read out the relevant entries from the map and pass them to the constructor - specifying a default in case it wasn't present.